# getting Warning: Function created with compilation errors

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I am getting error while executing the following function.I have been banging my head for quite sometime now.I am new to oracle so I am not able  to correct it.Can someone please help?

```
create or replace function rever(x int)
return number
is
y varchar2(30);
c varchar2(30);
v int;
begin
y:=to_char(x);
c:=reverse(y);
v:=to_number(c);
return v;
end rever;
/
```

the following is showing as error message

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
9/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
9/4      PLS-00201: identifier 'REVERSE' must be declared
```

Comment: Run `show errors` to see the error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PL/SQL `reverse()` function in Oracle. So this does not work:

```
declare
  v varchar2(20);
begin
  v:= reverse('krow not does ti');
  dbms_output.put_line(v);
end;  
/
```

It throws the PLS-00201 error you got.

However, there is an **undocumented** SQL function which we can use in PL/SQL, but only by invoking the SQL engine:

```
declare
  v varchar2(20);
begin
  select reverse('skrow ti') into v from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(v);
end;  
/
```

Of course, because `reverse()` is undocumented we're not supposed to use it, at least in production code. Not sure why it's undocumented. I think Oracle uses it for reverse indexes, so maybe there's some limit on reversible string size.

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f794296c6ab2cf99352ec967705f9293) demo.

---

> The performace is a bit worse

I think that is the cost of moving from the PL/SQL engine to the SQL engine and back again. So it comes down to use case. If we're writing a function  which will only be used in pure PL/SQL then I think your approach is the better one. But if we're writing a function to be used in SQL then I would consider using the Oracle built-in instead, even though it's not supported.

Although to be honest I can't remember the last time I used a `reverse()` function - Oracle's or hand-rolled - in real life (as opposed to answering questions in forums or similar Code Golf questions :) ).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did not know the function yet.
The performace is a bit worse, even with smaller values. *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ec00bb0a03dfb02b4813929950554ab)*

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not provide a function in plsql to do a string reverse.

```
     create or replace function rever(x int)
     return number
     is
       y varchar2(30);
       c varchar2(30);
       v int;
     begin
       y:=to_char(x);

       -- Loop other each char in a string from the last to the first element  
       for i in reverse 1.. length(y)
       loop 
         c:= c|| substr(y,i,1); 
       end loop; 
       v:=to_number(c);
       return v;
     end rever;
     /
```

**Test:**

```
     begin
       dbms_output.put_line(rever(1));
       dbms_output.put_line(rever(12));
       dbms_output.put_line(rever(21));
       dbms_output.put_line(rever(123));
     end;
     /
```

**Result:**

```
dbms_output
    1
    21
    12
    321
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=85e3bfede3f2526d4d91f9849560a4be)*

Comment: *"Oracle does not provide a function in plsql to do a string reverse."* but we can use the SQL function in PL/SQL. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773246/146325).

Comment: select reverse(c) into x from dual the following statement is getting executed.Why?can you plz explain..

Comment: because `reverse` is a function in SQL engine

Answer (score 1):

Just for amusement, without PL/SQL, using a little bit of regular expressions with hierarchical query:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Littlefoot' from dual)
  3  select listagg(one, '') within group (order by lvl desc) reversed
  4  from (select level lvl, regexp_substr(col, '.', 1, level) one
  5        from test
  6        connect by level <= length(col)
  7       );

REVERSED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
toofelttiL

SQL>
```

Or, rewritten as a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_reverse (par_col in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(1000);
  5  begin
  6    select listagg(one, '') within group (order by lvl desc)
  7      into retval
  8      from (select level lvl, regexp_substr(par_col, '.', 1, level) one
  9            from dual
 10            connect by level <= length(par_col)
 11           );
 12    return retval;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select empno, f_reverse(empno) rev_empno,
  2         ename, f_reverse(ename) rev_ename
  3  from emp
  4  where rownum <= 3;

     EMPNO REV_EMPNO  ENAME      REV_ENAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 9637       SMITH      HTIMS
      7499 9947       ALLEN      NELLA
      7521 1257       WARD       DRAW

SQL>
```